# crash on the mac with frameworks

Tags: macos, qt

I am an application developer and I am facing such a problem. We get crashes on sentry on different versions of mac (10.16.0(21E258), 10.16.0(20D64),
10.14.6(18G103)...) and in each such crash comes the following:

dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries,

Library not loaded: @rpath/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore

Referenced from:

/Applications/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/QtWebEngineProcess
Reason: no suitable image found.

Did find:
/Applications/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../../../../QtCore.framework/ Versions/5/QtCore: code signature in (/Applications/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../../ ../../QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary (signed with custom identity or adhoc?)

We also tried to reproduce this issue on our Macs and VMs with the versions listed, but found nothing. Also, judging by the number of reports, this problem is not constant and does not occur for everyone. Tell me, do you have any clues about this? (Of course, our application has certificates signed).

Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: What Qt version is that? Can you confirm that all the computers tested are running the exact same Qt version? This might be related to [QTBUG-71724](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-71724)

Comment: We are using 5.15.0 and this version on all machines tested. I also noticed that this problem only occurs in applications where there is QtWebEngine

Comment: Debug or Release? Does it make any difference if you [disable the sandbox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-platform-notes.html#sandboxing-support)?

Comment: Release.I haven't tried disabling sandbox, but the article would be quite interesting, before I try disabling it, tell me why you thought it would help?

Comment: Once I got a message like: unsealed contents present in the root directory of an embedded framework
Is subcomponent: myApp/Contents/Frameworks/QtCore.framework but this was a one time event and didn't crash. Command: coding --verify --deep --strict --verbose=2 myApp

Comment: That suggestion came from a QTBUG ticket that described a similar problem with QtWebEngine. I think @E4z9 suggestion makes a lot of sense.

Comment: This is weird. I use codesign --verify --deep --verbose=2 o sign all binaries and 99 percent of the time it works as I expect. Also, I looked at the signatures of all binaries for 5 versions of different macOS and everything is fine everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

> not valid for use in process using Library Validation: mapped file has no Team ID and is not a platform binary

You need to sign all frameworks and also binaries with the same ID and Team. It looks like `QtWebEngineProcess` is signed, but the `QtCore` that you ship with it is not.

See also https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me. I checked all the certificates on several macs. And everything is ok everywhere. I checked with spctl and codesign commands. Obviously, everything works correctly on these machines. Again, we keep getting crash logs from all the latest builds.

Comment: What does `codesign -dv /Applications/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app` show, and what does `codesign -dv /Applications/Contents/Frameworks/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Versions/5/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app/Contents/MacOS/../../../../../ ../../QtCore.framework` show? They must come up with the same `TeamIdentifier=` value.

Comment: Yes, TeamIdentifier is same.